# OpenGL: Results by gluUnProject are not the expected ones

Tags: c++, opengl

I am drawing a texture with z=0 as visible in the following image:

[image]

My near plane and far plane settings are 0.001 and 120.0. I can move around and zoom in and out using my keyboard.

What I want is to identify the world position of a mouse cursor position (e.g. red in the image) while using gluunproject.

**Problem:** The results posX, posY and posZ are somewhat close but not correct. E.g. for the center of the visible view (blue) I get posX=8.90000 and posY=53.80000. However if I move the mouse to the left I get posX=8.89894 (should be 3.xx). If I move the cursor to the right I get 8.90103 instead of approx. 14-16.

#### Here is my code:

```
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
 
perspectiveGL(65.0,(GLdouble)width()/(GLdouble)height(), 0.001, 120.0); 
 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
 
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 
// Go to current World-Position
glTranslated(-m_posWorld.x(), -m_posWorld.y(), -m_posWorld.z());
 
 
// Try to project Screen(Mouse)-Coordinates to World Coordinates
GLint viewport[4];
GLdouble modelview[16];
GLdouble projection[16];
GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
 
glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );
glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );
 
winX = (float)m_lastPos.x(); // m_lastPos is a Point storing the last Mouse Cursor Position within the OpenGL-Widget (without borders)
winY = (float)viewport[3]-(float)m_lastPos.y();
winZ = -m_posWorld.z();
 
GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;
int success = glhUnProjectf( winX, winY, -m_posWorld.z(), modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: No offense, but how did you earn so much reputation and a gold badge without knowing not to link to a pastebin for code? _(I have fixed this for you)._

Answer (score 2):

#### To *"unproject"* something, you need window-space `x`,`y` *and* `z`.

*`m_posWorld.z` almost certainly is not in window-space.*

Window-space `z` is what the depth buffer stores, it is a value between [**0.0**, **1.0**] (assuming default depth range). Because the depth buffer gives you this value, you can easily figure it out by reading the depth buffer back at `(winX, winY)` (though performance will suffer).

#### You can transform your world-space coordinate into window-space:

```
vec4 posClip  = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * m_posWorld; // Project to clip-space
vec4 posNDC   = posClip / posClip.w;                        // Perspective Divide
float winZ    = (posNDC * vec4 (0.5) + vec4 (0.5)).z;       // Adjust for Depth Range
```

The approach discussed above will work much quicker, but requires some matrix math. You are currently relying completely on OpenGL itself to do your matrix math for you, and if you want to keep doing that your only option will be to read the depth buffer back:

```
GLfloat winZ;
glReadPixels (winX, winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. winZ seems to be always '1'? If I am using winZ obtained by glReadPixels within glhUnProjectf posZ becomes a negative value. Example: posWorld.z is 4 -> posZ becomes approx -116 which is -(120.00 - 4) (120 is my zFar value). posX and posY contain strange values for the "current view", e.g. x -> [-114,131] and y [-20,130]. If I am using the negative winZ-value within glhUnProjectf posZ is almost equal to posWorldZ and posX and posY are close to the real values but behave like in my initial post (only the 4. or 5. decimal places change). Any thoughts?

Comment: @Anonymous: It would help if you added `glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST)`. Nothing will be written to the depth buffer without that ;) As for getting a negative object-space Z coordinate back, that is kind of expected because the default projection matrix in OpenGL inverts the Z-axis.

Comment: My initialization routine contains the following calls:         glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc (GL_LEQUAL);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH);
I am running out of ideas... would it help if I would provide my Qt Creator project in a simplified version?